# Unable to load Ubuntu on Toshiba Laptop

Tags: boot, uefi, certificates

```
Error: 16.0944491 problem loading UEFI:db X.509 certificate (-65)
```

This error message occurred while trying to load Ubuntu on a Toshiba laptop. What does it mean?

Comment: Can you disable the TPM in the BIOS? If so, try installation again after doing so.

Comment: Which Ubuntu release is this and for which architecture, i686 (32 bit) or amd64 (64 bit)?

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with this and had disabled secure boot- I changed my EUFI to a CSM/legacy bios which worked perfect.